# Session service unique id initialization with Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, ioc-container, autofac

I have a Windows service project where i'm using Autofac as IOC container. This service is 'sniffing' mails from a exchange server, so everytime some event happens on the exchange server my Windows service checks if that new item should be copied somewhere else other than the exchange server.

For every event happing (mail send, mail recieved, new task ect) i would like to have a unique session id which i can use for logging. Then it will be easier to track down an exchange server event in the log (using NLog).

I have tried the following but i get a new guid everytime. I would like only a new guid per session/exchange server event:

In my autofac setup class (bootstrapper.cs)

```
builder.RegisterType<SessionService>().As<ISessionService>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

I also tried with this, but same result:

```
builder.RegisterType<SessionService>().As<ISessionService>()
```

My session service implementation:

```
public class SessionService : ISessionService
{
    private readonly Guid _sessionGuid;

    public SessionService()
    {
        _sessionGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid GetNewSessionGuid()
    {
        return _sessionGuid;
    }
}
```

Then for example i have to log something when trying to save information from the exchange server event to other systems. Could be just info or it could be errors, either way it should be the same guid for the event.

So for example in my `PushNotificationListener` class i use Property injection:

```
public ILogger Logger
{
    get
    {
        using (var scope = IocContainer.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            return scope.Resolve<ILogger>();
        }
    }
}

public ILogFormater LogFormater
{
    get
    {
        using (var scope = IocContainer.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            return scope.Resolve<ILogFormater>();
        }
    }
}

public ISessionService SessionService
{
    get
    {
        using (var scope = IocContainer.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            return IocContainer.Container.Resolve<ISessionService>();
        }
    }
}
```

Then i call the sessionservice for the guid like this:

```
Logger.LogInfo(LogFormater.EventLogFormat(
    SessionService.GetNewSessionGuid(),
    exchangeEventType.ToString(),
    message.Notification.ItemsElementName[count].ToString(),
    _service.ImpersonatedUserId.Id,
    mailEvent.TimeStamp));
```

And in my MailService class i have first the constructor, so you can see the depencies injections:

```
public MailService(
    ILogger logger,
    ILogFormater logFormater,
    ISessionService sessionService)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _logFormater = logFormater;
    _sessionService = sessionService;
}
```

And the i call session guid when for example a new mail have been save in another system:

```
_logger.LogInfo(_sessionService.GetNewSessionGuid().ToString());
```

The call to the _sessionService.GetNewSessionGuid() method in PushNotificationListener class and in the MailService class give me two different guids.

I want them to be the same guid. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by your properties in the `PushNotificationListener` class. Since you create new lifetime scopes in their, within that scope a new `SessionService` will be created. Prevent doing this.

Instead, there should only be one lifetime scope for each session. You should create a new lifetime scope (and only one lifetime scope) directly after the event is raised and before you resolve the root object. From that point on, all dependencies should be injected using constructor injection. This ensures that within that scope, there is only one `SessionService`.

Comment: I see your point, but i'm having trouble with using construtor injection on the PushNotificationListener class, so i was hoping to use Property injection. Why doesn't it work when i remove this: using (var scope = IocContainer.Container.BeginLifetimeScope()) from the SessionService property? From what i understand it should use the scope that i initialised in the bootstapper class.

Comment: In fact, you're not doing property injection at all. The properties are not injected. You are using the service locator pattern. You can inject the dependencies into properties, but prevent wrapping them in their own lifetime scope, because in that case you'll obviously get a new `SessionService` instance for each scope. Might might want to ask a new question on SO to let us help you with the problems you're having with constructor injection.